# Typescript converting JSON to string - Type string is not assignable to type = '{ .. }'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have this code:

```
interface ISource extends IdModel {
  source_type_id: number;
  network_id: number;
  company_connection_id: number;
  feed_id: number;
  connection_id: number;
  feed_ids: number[];
  name: string;
  tag: string;
  additional_data: ISourceData;
  default_user_image?: File;
  hasNewImage?: boolean;
  next_update?: string;
  post_field_overrides?: {
    user_full_name?: string;
    user_screen_name?: string;
    url?: string;
    network_id?: number;
  };
}

save() {
   //converting this to string because I am saving this in my database.
   this.source.post_field_overrides = JSON.stringify(this.source.post_field_overrides);

}
```

If I don't convert that into string, that value that's being saved in my DB is `[Object object]`.

If I also convert that into String, I am getting this error/warning:

```
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ user_full_name?: string | undefined; user_screen_name?: string | undefined; url?: string | undefined; network_id?: number | undefined; } | undefined'.
```

Any help on this, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `post_field_overrides?` is neither string nor any... You should decide what you want it to be and write that I guess...

Comment: did you try this?: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.source.post_field_overrides));

Answer (score 2):

`this.source.post_field_overrides = JSON.stringify(this.source.post_field_overrides);`

you have defined post_field_overrides as an object containing

```
{
    user_full_name?: string;
    user_screen_name?: string;
    url?: string;
    network_id?: number;
  }
```

in your typescript interface. now you want to replace the same atrribute with a string. this won't pass typescript's static type check.

if you need it to be a string , add another attribute in your interface.

or as Alexei Levenkov said ,use this instead to support both object and string

```
post_field_overrides?: string | {
    user_full_name?: string;
    user_screen_name?: string;
    url?: string;
    network_id?: number;
  };
```

Comment: This one is really good! Thanks for this! Another problem is when I retrieve the data from the database, since it is a string, i have to `JSON.parse()` it the moment I retrieved it. This is how I parse it - `this.source.post_field_overrides = JSON.parse(this.source.post_field_overrides);`,
The problem with that is I am getting again the error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ` - how to do that?

Comment: I guess when you use JSON.parse to parse the string into object, typescript type checking will just see it as JSON Object not type  `{ user_full_name: ...}`  you defined in the interface.   So you may need to abstract this type definition as an independent type PostFieldOverride, use it in the interface as well as this place with  `JSON.parse(this.source.post_field_overrides) as PostFieldOverride`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `post_field_overrides` as object

```
 post_field_overrides?: {
    user_full_name?: string;
    user_screen_name?: string;
    url?: string;
    network_id?: number;
  };
```

if you need to use it as an String you need to declare as:

```
 post_field_overrides?: string;
```